# Jhipster/Spring Kafka Consumer with a Python Producer

Tags: java, python, spring, apache-kafka, jhipster

I'm trying to make a Python Producer that sends a message to JHipster. I implemented the easy example proposed in their website:

http://www.jhipster.tech/using-kafka/

I'm trying to send the same message but instead of using a resource with a rest path, i use a Python script that sends a simple message.

Here is my python script, which sends a string to the same topic **subscribableChannel**:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
#  connect to Kafka
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:3000')
# Assign a topic
topic = 'subscribableChannel'

def send_a_message():
    producer.send_messages(topic, 'Nice_test').get(timeout=30)
    print('done emitting')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    send_a_message()
```

When I run the code, it takes some time and then I get: `kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable`. Therefore my question is what is the procedure to follow in order to implement this producer/consumer functionality

Comment: Port 3000 is not a default Kafka port. Check over that link again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka runs on port 9092, not 3000

```
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')
```